# Number fields with given discriminant

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, number-fields, discriminant

In the special case of number fields that are the splitting fields of irreducible polynomials of degree 5 or 6 with Symmetric Galois group (so degree 120 or 720 over Q), is there a good upper bound on how many different ones can exist with a given discriminant D, as a function of D?